# ¿Dónde está y cómo se genera la página de login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

https://github.com/in28minutes/deploy-spring-boot-to-azure/tree/master/02-todo-web-application-h2

Estoy arrancando este repositorio en local pero no entiendo de dónde se saca la página inicial de login ya que no figura entre los archivos del código fuente. Veo que se está generando en algún sitio pero no sé dónde.

¿Alquien entiende dónde se está llamando a esa página?

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, te agradecería que hubieras subido el POM a stackoverflow, porque de normal aquí no solemos responder preguntas donde no hay nada explicado, sólo enlaces.

Pero como yo me tiré más de 3h revisando todo con el mismo problema, te voy a comentar la solución para que el siguiente que venga aquí, pueda solucionarlo antes.

En tu pom tienes puesto la siguiente dependencia:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Si deseas mantener Spring Security (y, por tanto, el login obligatorio para acceder al sistema), te recomiendo echar un vistazo sobre "evitar" el login con otro sistema de sesión, échale un vistazo al método `WebSecurityConfig` (podrás encontrar más información por internet). Con ese método puedes indicar qué hacer en cada petición y eliminar el inicio de sesión obligatorio para poder acceder al sistema.